# How do I do a moving sum forwards in KDB?

Tags: kdb

I want to sum up the next 5 days returns (`target`) in my query.

It's working as:

```
 select date, zR, target: -5 xprev (5 msum zR) from a where sym=`AAPL
```

What I don't understand is why `-5 msum zR` doesn't work:

```
 select date, zR, target: -5 msum zR from a where sym=`AAPL
```

Is there a more elegant 'KDB' way of writing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x#y` creates a list of length `x` made up of elements from y. So in your second example you have a `date` and `zR` column the same length as `a`, but your `target` column is of length 5. Since tables need to have columns of the same length, you will see an error in this case.

I don't think there's anything wrong with how you are currently doing it, your query will let you know `target` on the start of each 5 day perdiod.
You could definitely drop the parentheses around `5 msum zR` as kdb doesn't care about these (evaluation is strictly right to left).

You will be left with nulls due to the fact you are moving the elements in your array, so you will need to find a way to fill these (if that's what you want to do).

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Sean in that there's nothing wrong with the approach you've taken. It's a pity that `-5 msum zR` doesn't work as it's somewhat intuitive but Kx haven't added that functionality into `msum`. You could always suggest it to them.

An alternative approach is to use `next` to shift and then sum:

```
q)t:([]date:.z.D+til 10;sym:`AAPL;zR:til 10)
q)update target:sum 1_5 next\zR by sym from t
date       sym  zR target
-------------------------
2021.10.05 AAPL 0  15
2021.10.06 AAPL 1  20
2021.10.07 AAPL 2  25
2021.10.08 AAPL 3  30
2021.10.09 AAPL 4  35
2021.10.10 AAPL 5
2021.10.11 AAPL 6
2021.10.12 AAPL 7
2021.10.13 AAPL 8
2021.10.14 AAPL 9
```